# Ansible tower credential type is not setting environment variables

Tags: python-3.x, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

Context:

1. I am running Ansible AWX/Tower that is connected to a Git Repository as Project Source.
2. I have Dynamic inventory defined using plugin (azure_rm).
3. I have created a service principle in Azure AD that has proper access (confirmed).
4. I am using that service principal in Ansible tower to run the dynamic inventory with azure_rm plugin. But it fails every time.

Code:

1. I have created a custom credential that sets up the environment variables. The environment variables that are supposed to set are defined as required for service principal in documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.html)

```
# Input configuration
fields:
  - id: client_id
    type: string
    label: Client ID
  - id: client_secret
    type: string
    label: Client Secret
    secret: true
  - id: tenant_id
    type: string
    label: Tenant ID
  - id: subscription_id
    type: string
    label: Subscription ID
required:
  - client_id
  - client_secret
  - tenant_id
```

```
# Output Configuration
env:
  AZURE_CLIENT_ID: '{{ client_id }}'
  AZURE_SECRET: '{{ client_secret }}'
  AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: '{{ subscription_id }}'
  AZURE_TENANT: '{{ tenant_id }}'
```

2. Above credential type is used to create a credential and used in Inventory Source.
3. The Inventory Source is following:

```
plugin: azure_rm

batch_fetch: yes
cert_validation_mode: ignore

group_by_os_family: yes

include_vm_resource_groups:
- exampleRG
```

4. Here is the error I get every time:

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse
/tmp/awx_64_77si0uqt/project/inventories/development/hosts.yml with auto
plugin: inventory config
'/tmp/awx_64_77si0uqt/project/inventories/development/hosts.yml' could not be
verified by plugin 'azure_rm'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 280, in parse_source
    plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/auto.py", line 56, in parse
    raise AnsibleParserError("inventory config '{0}' could not be verified by plugin '{1}'".format(path, plugin_name))
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse
/tmp/awx_64_77si0uqt/project/inventories/development/hosts.yml with yaml
plugin: Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 280, in parse_source
    plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/yaml.py", line 112, in parse
    raise AnsibleParserError('Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory')
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse
/tmp/awx_64_77si0uqt/project/inventories/development/hosts.yml with ini plugin:
Invalid host pattern 'plugin:' supplied, ending in ':' is not allowed, this
character is reserved to provide a port.
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 280, in parse_source
    plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/ini.py", line 138, in parse
    raise AnsibleParserError(e)
[WARNING]: Unable to parse
/tmp/awx_64_77si0uqt/project/inventories/development/hosts.yml as an inventory
source
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /tmp/awx_64_77si0uqt/project/inventories/development
as an inventory source
ERROR! No inventory was parsed, please check your configuration and options.
```

Also, this works when running in local ansible cli after setting the environment variables manually. So, obvious suspiction is AWX is not setting the environment variables as expectd and error log is not super helpful.

This is my second day on this error. Appreciate any insights. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using the built-in [Microsoft Azure Resource Manager](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/credentials.html#microsoft-azure-resource-manager) Credential?

But specifically, your error seems to be due to the fact that the azure_rm inventory plugin is not validating your `inventories/development/hosts.yml`. As stated in the [azure_rm_inventory synopsis](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_inventory.html#synopsis):

> Requires a YAML configuration file whose name ends with ‘azure_rm.(yml|yaml)’

Answer (score 0):

I know some time has passed but I had the same issue and solve it using this:

Notice:

- You to create a standard Azure RM Credential in tower/awx This only
- Happened to me with AWX with Pay Tower is not needed.

  ```
    - name : Setting Azure ARM credential facts
      set_fact:
          client_id:  "{{ lookup('env', 'AZURE_CLIENT_ID') }}"
          clent_secret: "{{ lookup('env', 'AZURE_SECRET') }}"
          tenant: "{{ lookup('env', 'AZURE_TENANT') }}"
          subscription: "{{ lookup('env', 'AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID') }}"
      no_log: true
  ```